# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/actions/MappingDispatchAction

Tags: java, struts, weblogic, classpath, ear

I have an EAR deployed in Weblogic 10.3.6.0 and I get the next error:

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/actions/MappingDispatchAction
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:630)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:614)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.findClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:101)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:86)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:630)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:614)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:630)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:614)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
        at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationClass(RequestUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationInstance(RequestUtils.java:143)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionCreate(RequestProcessor.java:280)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:218)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
        at mx.com.softtek.infra.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:93)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3739)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3705)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2282)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

The structure for my ear is:

```
App.ear
---- META-INF
        --- Application.xml
        --- Manifest.mf (empty)
        --- weblogic-application.xml
--- App.war
        ---  jsp files
        ---  META-INF
                  -- Manifest.mf (empty)
                  -- Context.xml
        ---  WEB-INF
                  -- classes
                  -- lib
                  -- tags
                  -- tld
                  -- applicationContext.xml
                  -- struts-config.xml
                  -- validator-rules.xml
                  -- web.xml
```

This error appears when I log in the application (the index.jsp is ok and the application is loaded good , without problems). For example , I get access to "myapplication/login/" and I put the user and password and when I push the buttom "Log in"  is when the struts library begins to work.

I think that is a problem with the manifest.mf and the classpath , but I tried  several times and nothing works. Somebody can help me?
Thanks

---

Comment: Could be possible some static initialization went wrong, and this is a symptom of it later on in the process. Do you see any exceptions on Weblogic startup?

Comment: Hello , thanks for the reply.

I don´t see exceptions on Weblogic startup.
If I deploy the ".war" no problems on Tomcat and the application works correctly.

Comment: next question would be what is in the lib folder? does it have the jar that contains MappingDispatchAction?

Comment: Yes. The lib folder contains the library struts (and more).
Struts.jar contains the next structure:

     
       -- META-INF
          -- Manifest.mf
       -- org
          -- apache
              -- struts
                  -- actions 
                      -- MappingDispatchAction.class
                      -- more classes...
                  -- more folders ...

Comment: Could it be because weblogic is looking at APP-INF by default instead of WEB-INF like tomcat?

Comment: I try putting the library struts.jar within of APP-INF/lib and did not work. The application is deployed, but can not access it (404).

Comment: Only struts.jar? Or the entire lib? I'd try copying the entire directory

Comment: I copy the entire directory and it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to paste the whole error. In the past I have seen that it could be due to the fact that you do not have the required class but some instances of this have occurred due to class conflicts.

Please verify these:
 1. Do you have multiple jar's referencing this particular class and/or do you have multiple versions of the class file?
 2. Since you are using 10.3.6, have you tried using wls-cat? 
 3. Are all your database connections accurate and functional? Please un-target and re-target all your data sources.

Trouble shooting will be a lot simpler with the whole error and unfortunately, I can not comment so I had to make this an answer. I will edit it soon as I see the whole error.

Comment: I just edit my question by adding the total mistake, you could help me?

Comment: were you able to verify that there was no conflict in class files, version-wise. Also please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339696/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-struts-action-actionservlet and http://www.mkyong.com/struts/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-struts-action-forwardaction/